# Can sinon stub withArgs match some but not all arguments

Tags: sinon

I have a function I am stubbing that gets called with multiple arguments. I want to check **just the first argument**. The rest are callback function, so I want to leave them alone. Thus, I might have the following 2 calls, using ajax as an example:

```
method.get = sinon.stub();
method.get(25,function(){/* success callback */},function(){/* error callback */});         
method.get(10,function(){/* success callback */},function(){/* error callback */});
```

I cannot use `method.get.calls...` because then it doesn't differentiate between the first one `get(25)` and the second `get(10)`. But if I use `method.get.withArgs(25).calls...` then it does not match either, because `withArgs()` matches **all** arguments, which this does not (and never could, with callbacks like that).

How do I get sinon stubs to check and set responses based on just the 1st arg?

Comment: How come the behaviour that I am witnessing is opposite to what you are saying here? If I write ```const methodStub = stub(); methodStub.withArgs(25).returns(1);```, then ```console.log(methodStub(25));``` will print 1 and so will ```console.log(methodStub(25, 26));```. Do you think it might have changed since you posted this question?

Comment: @Avius the information in the question is incorrect, `withArgs` **does not** match all arguments. I've added an answer below with the details.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/matchers/#sinonmatchany

You can use sinon.match.any:

```
method.get.withArgs(25, sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any);
```

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if I could do `method.get.withFirstArgs(25)` and thus as long as `arg[0]` is `25` it would match, but I guess it doesn't exist.

Comment: Works great!  [Here's a fixed link](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v3.2.1/matchers/#sinonmatchany) to the latest `sinon.match.any` docs.

Comment: match.any doesnt work with any function matching

Answer (score 8):

### Solution

`withArgs` *can* be used to match some but not all the arguments.

Specifically, `method.get.withArgs(25)` *will* check **just the first argument**.

---

### Correction

This is incorrect:

> `withArgs()` matches **all** arguments

---

### Details

When `withArgs` is called it remembers the arguments it was passed [here](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/eae7d4a66b5b6d6d054520e395fb92c3db59db99/lib/sinon/spy.js#L330) as `matchingArguments`.

Then when the `stub` is called it gets all matching fakes [here](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/eae7d4a66b5b6d6d054520e395fb92c3db59db99/lib/sinon/stub.js#L121).

[`matchingFakes`](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/eae7d4a66b5b6d6d054520e395fb92c3db59db99/lib/sinon/spy.js#L361-L365) is called without a second parameter so it returns all fakes that have `matchingArguments` [that match the arguments passed to the `stub` starting at index 0 up to the length of `matchingArguments`](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/eae7d4a66b5b6d6d054520e395fb92c3db59db99/lib/sinon/spy.js#L371).  This means that a fake will match when its `matchingArguments` match the beginning of the arguments passed *even if there are additional arguments*.

Any matching fakes are then [sorted by `matchingArguments.length`](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/eae7d4a66b5b6d6d054520e395fb92c3db59db99/lib/sinon/stub.js#L123-L125) and the one that matches the most arguments is the one that is [invoked](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/blob/eae7d4a66b5b6d6d054520e395fb92c3db59db99/lib/sinon/stub.js#L126).

---

The following test confirms this behavior and passes with `sinon` version `1.1.0` from 7 years ago, version `1.14.0` from the time this question was asked, and the current version `6.3.5`:

```js
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

test('withArgs', () => {

  const stub = sinon.stub();

  stub.withArgs(25).returns('first arg is 25!');
  stub.returns('default response');

  expect(stub(25)).toBe('first arg is 25!');  // SUCCESS
  expect(stub(25, function () { }, function () { })).toBe('first arg is 25!');  // SUCCESS
  expect(stub(10, function () { }, function () { })).toBe('default response');  // SUCCESS

});
```

Comment: You answered this on my birthday and it's exactly what I needed ✨

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check the first argument you can use

```
method.get.withArgs(25).calledOnce
```

or

```
method.get.calledWith(25)
```

Answer (score 2):

this method works very well with spies if you want to check only one argument among many

```
it('should check only first argument', function ():void {
            myFunction('foo', 'bar', baz');
            expect(myFunctionSpy.firstCall.args[0]).to.equal('foo');
        });
```

However I don't understand why you are using stubs here. If you just want to check how the function is called you should use a spy. If you want to check how it's called AND change it's behaviour (ex: blocking ajax calls) then you should use a mock.

Sinon mocks have their own way of checking stuff. The only way I know for your case would be to use sinon.match.many for the arguments you don't want to check:

```
it('should check only first argument', async function (): Promise<void> {
                mock.expects('myFunction').withExactArgs('foo', sinon.match.any, sinon.match.any).returns('foo');
                await myFunction('foo', 'bar', baz');
                mock.verify();
            });
```

mock.verify() will proceed to the test AND reset the mock for other tests, in case of using a spy or a stub you should do it mannually with restore() or reset() after each test

PD: sorry about TypeScript syntax here :p