# Sinon stub withExactArgs?

Tags: sinon

Sinon mocks have a method withExactArgs, which asserts the number of arguments passed to the method in question. Is there a way to have this behaviour using stubs?

Right now they seem to work like this:

```
const methodStub = stub();
methodStub.withArgs().returns(1);
console.log(methodStub()); // prints 1
console.log(methodStub({})); // also prints 1
```

I would like to have an **exact** argument match. I have looked into adding a custom behaviour to sinon, which didn't work out. I don't really know what to try next.

I am aware that I can check the arguments after the calls have been made, but I feel like the cleanliness of the test written that way does not fare.

Also, this reasonably well-received post on SO has me *very* confused: [Can sinon stub withArgs match some but not all arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442849/can-sinon-stub-withargs-match-some-but-not-all-arguments). Quote:

> if I use method.get.withArgs(25).calls... then it does not match either, because withArgs() matches **all** arguments

I seem to be observing the complete opposite with Sinon v6, exactly the behaviour that the OP was looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement from the linked question is incorrect:

> `withArgs()` matches **all** arguments

`withArgs` **does not** match all arguments.  I've added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52711904/10149510) with details.

---

`withExactArgs` for a `stub` [has been discussed but never implemented](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/461).

---

So yes, checking the arguments after the calls have been made, using `callsFake` with a custom function, adding custom behavior, or using a `mock` instead of a `stub` are the current options in `sinon` for asserting that a method was called with exact args.

---

As an example, the stub from the question looks like it should only return `1` if it is called with no arguments which can be done using `callsFake`:

```js
test('stub exact args', () => {
  const stub = sinon.stub();
  stub.callsFake((...args) => {
    if (args.length === 0) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 'default response';
  });

  expect(stub()).toBe(1);  // SUCCESS
  expect(stub({})).toBe('default response');  // SUCCESS
});
```

Comment: Basically confirming my understanding, which is probably what I was looking for.